# stop task from running when file is open

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks, vba

I am trying to schedule a task in Window's Task Scheduler that opens an excel file and auto run the macro in it.

The macro part is all done, but one problem I have is when the file is already open and the scheduled task runs. Whenever this happens, it will ask you if you want to reopen the file, if i accidentally click yes, which actually happened, then the data I was working on will all disappear.

So what I want is for the task to not run when file is open. Do I need to run a script? create a batch file with the code? If possible can you provide me a code that can do this as I am not familiar with another language aside from VBA

**Note**.
Just to clarify, I have a file that constantly pull data form Live Bloomberg. What I want to do is to save it as another workbook for reference everyday at 4:30pm. There is a few problem.
Here is how what I wrote in ThisWorkbook for easier understanding what I want to accomplish

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:30:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

1)If I didn't open that excel that day, Workbook_Open() simply won't run.

2)Even if I did open the excel, if I close Excel before 4:30pm the macro won't run

So what I want is to have windows task scheduler constantly open the excel file for me that will always run on time regardless of what happens.

There are other problems too. I always write comments and stuff to the Live Data File, so if Task Scheduler tries to open the data file which in turn activating the Workbook_Open() while I am using it, a popup will come up asking if I want to reopen file. Of course I simply need to press "no" then the task will stop and everything is fine. But what if I wasn't there to press the button? Also on a few occasion I accidentally press "yes", which wiped out all the comments I wrote.

Therefore what I wanted to ask is that if The Live Data File is already open, simply make it so that the task in Task Scheduler won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks Steve S for your input.

I already did a workaround. Instead of having the LiveData file to run the macro, I put the macro on a clean excel template and have task scheduler open that file instead. This way is much more reliable and skips all the "Scripting in task scheduler" thing.

Here is my updated code:

```
'In ThisWorkbook
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run "AutoSaveAs"
End Sub


'In Module1
Public Sub AutoSaveAs()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LDSP As String
    Dim IsOTF
    Dim LDS, TWB As Workbook

    'Set LiveDealSheet file path
    'Check if LiveDealSheet is already open
    LDSP = "I:\LiveDealSheet\LiveDealSheet.xlsm"
    IsOTF = IsWorkBookOpen(LDSP)

    'Set quick workbook shortcut
    Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
    If IsOTF = False Then
        Set LDS = Workbooks.Open(LDSP)
    Else
        Workbooks("LiveDealSheet.xlsm").Activate
        Set LDS = ActiveWorkbook
    End If

    'Copy all data from LIVE Deals to TWB
    LDS.Sheets("LIVE Deals").Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    TWB.Sheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial (xlValues)
    TWB.Sheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial (xlFormats)


    TWB.SaveAs FileName:="I:\LiveDealSheet\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & " LiveDealSheet", FileFormat:=52

    If IsOTF = False Then
        LDS.Close False
        TWB.Close False
    Else
        TWB.Close False
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Workbook.ReadOnly Property?  This won't exactly tell you if the file is open but it will tell you if you have write-access.  Try:

```
Public Sub OnlyRunWithWriteAccess()
    Dim oBook As Workbook
    Set oBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    If Not oBook.ReadOnly Then
        'Your processing code goes here...
    End If
    Set oBook = Nothing

End Sub
```